# How to apply A* algorithm to a Tic Tac Toe game?

Tags: algorithm

My teacher asked me to write a Tic Tac Toe game using A* algorithm. I don't know how I can use A* in my game. Is it possible to check winner using A*? Or can it be used for something else?

Comment: Do you know how A* works? Do you know how graphs work? Do you know how to represent a start and goal state of your game as nodes in your graph?  You need to ask a concrete question because right now it's just too broad

Comment: I don't really see how A* can help here. The heuristic function you would be much like the evaluation function that is used in minimax/alpha-beta searches. But one characteristic of A* is that it maintains a priority queue of searches at different depths, then choosing the most promising from those to extend it. But both players have different goals, so a position with X to move has a different goal than a position with O to move. How would you have a fair comparison between two such positions to choose one to investigate deeper?

Answer (score -1):

you should extend you game,the grid graph should not be 3x3,may be 20x20.
and give a initial situation,you should quickly work out the least steps that you can win the game,its like a dfs problem,then you can use A*,because A* is for optimization problem.